# Angular.js - Include markup in an expression

Tags: angularjs

I have the following piece of code -

```
<div class="appReviewQuestions">
{{aboutYou.radioSelectSQ}}                          
</div>
```

The expression `{{aboutYou.radioSelectSQ}}` initially represented a String but my application was updated and now the same expression represents String + markup(HTML).

Currently this piece of code shows the markup as a string. I want that Angular should read the markup and not display it as a string. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I just added the example from the docs as a comment to my answer. Check it out! (I'm guessing you forgot to inject 'ngSanitize' into your application)... let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` should do the trick!

```
<div class="appReviewQuestions">
  <p ng-bind-html="aboutYou.radioSelectSQ"></p>                          
</div>
```

Read more about it at the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: DId you include ngSanitize module?

Comment: @ArchitArora Here is a working example: [ng-bind-html example](https://plnkr.co/edit/70KeHgfq3ZbYW7HYExjw?p=preview)